# How to ensure the probing order of SPI bus?

Tags: kernel, device-tree, modprobe

I've an embedded linux system based on a iMX8 CPU. I'm upgrading the yocto-version and therefore the kernel version.

I've two SPI devices on two SPI buses. The device on the second bus has a driver which creates a `/dev/spidevX.X` `node`, the other does not create `/dev/*` `node`.

I've noticed addresses of SPI devices seems to be not consistent during kernel upgrades: On the previous yocto-version `Kernel 5.4.24`, my device on the second hardware SPI bus appears as `/dev/spidev1.0` consistently.

After the upgrade to Kernel 5.15.71, the node mostly appears as `/dev/spidev2.0`, but I've also seen `/dev/spidev1.0`.

My google results suggest that the /`dev/spidevX.Y`v means `X = bus`, `Y = device/CS`.

How can I ensure a certain hardware bus always gets a certain bus number?

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely to me. The device tree assignes the numbering of buses. Can you please add the SPI part of your dts to the question? Also the `dmesg` output for successful and unsuccessful probing?

Answer (score 0):

spidev (drivers/spi/spidev.c) creates /dev/spidevB.C where B is the bus number and C is the chip select:

```
dev = device_create(spidev_class, &spi->dev, spidev->devt,
            spidev, "spidev%d.%d",
            spi->master->bus_num, spi->chip_select);
```

Considering how the SPI core `drivers/spi/spi.c`

`int spi_register_controller(struct spi_controller *ctlr)`

assigns the controller bus number (code shown below), there are several ways you can run into an inconsistency between kernels (though unlikely).

Compare the SPI controllers in SoC device tree between the two kernel versions and see if there's an inconsistency in definitions and resolve it:

For example, like missing to define certain controllers in one version.

If there are no such inconsistencies, then check the device tree aliases for any inconsistency and resolve it (where `of_alias_get_id` and `of_alias_get_highest_id` in the code below can come into play):

Just an imaginary example,

in 5.4.y for the SoC

```
aliases {
    :
    spi0 = &ecspi1;
    spi1 = &ecspi2;
    spi2 = &ecspi3;
};
```

but in 5.15.y for the SoC

```
aliases {
    :
    spi0 = &ecspi3;
    spi1 = &ecspi1;
    spi2 = &ecspi2;
};
```

If your device tree doesn't have any aliases for SPIs and you are running into the inconsistency, try adding the SPI alias using the same number in both trees for the controller:

For example,

```
aliases {
    :
    spi0 = &lpspi1;
};
```

So, here we are using number **0** after the stem **spi** so `of_alias_get_id` or `of_alias_get_highest_id` can pick that.

I didn't specifically check the kernel versions you mentioned, and you didn't mention the iMX8 SoC (but by looking at lf-5.4.y and lf-5.15.y it's likely that it's iMX8QXP because I don't see SPI controllers in the DT, so you'll have to define them, so it's possible to run into an inconsistency there, but I don't know for sure).

SPI controller bus number assignment from `drivers/spi/spi.c`

```
int spi_register_controller(struct spi_controller *ctlr)
{

    if (ctlr->bus_num >= 0) {
        /* devices with a fixed bus num must check-in with the num */
        mutex_lock(&board_lock);
        id = idr_alloc(&spi_master_idr, ctlr, ctlr->bus_num,
            ctlr->bus_num + 1, GFP_KERNEL);
        mutex_unlock(&board_lock);
        if (WARN(id < 0, "couldn't get idr"))
            return id == -ENOSPC ? -EBUSY : id;
        ctlr->bus_num = id;
    } else if (ctlr->dev.of_node) {
        /* allocate dynamic bus number using Linux idr */
        id = of_alias_get_id(ctlr->dev.of_node, "spi");
        if (id >= 0) {
            ctlr->bus_num = id;
            mutex_lock(&board_lock);
            id = idr_alloc(&spi_master_idr, ctlr, ctlr->bus_num,
                       ctlr->bus_num + 1, GFP_KERNEL);
            mutex_unlock(&board_lock);
            if (WARN(id < 0, "couldn't get idr"))
                return id == -ENOSPC ? -EBUSY : id;
        }
    }
    if (ctlr->bus_num < 0) {
        first_dynamic = of_alias_get_highest_id("spi");
        if (first_dynamic < 0)
            first_dynamic = 0;
        else
            first_dynamic++;

        mutex_lock(&board_lock);
        id = idr_alloc(&spi_master_idr, ctlr, first_dynamic,
                   0, GFP_KERNEL);
        mutex_unlock(&board_lock);
        if (WARN(id < 0, "couldn't get idr"))
            return id;
        ctlr->bus_num = id;
    }

}
```